Using Bass-Serre theory to determine the strucure of a subgroup of a free construction
Suppose that we have $G^* = HNN(G,H,t)$ a HNN-extension. If $K = \langle \bar{G},t \rangle$ where $\bar{G} \leq G$, then is it true that $K = HNN(\bar{G},\bar{G}\cap H,t)$? How to determine the structure of $K$ using graph of groups?

I will try to describe explicitly my attempt.
It is well known that the graph of groups of $G^*$ is $(\mathcal{G},\bar{\Gamma})$ where $\bar{\Gamma}$ has one vertex $v$ and one edge $e$. The vertex group is $G^*(v) = G$ and the edge group is $G^*(e) = H$. We have the maps
$$\partial_0: G^*(e) \to G^*(d_0(e))$$
and
$$\partial_1: G^*(e) \to G^*(d_1(e))$$
where $\partial_0$ is just the inclusion and $\partial_1(h) = h^t$ where $t$ satisfies $t^{-1}ht = h^t$. So we have two distinct monomorphisms of $H$ to $G$ which generates an isomorphism between two subgroups necessary to define an HNN-extension.
We can define an action of $G^*$ on its standard tree $S$ (Bass-Serre tree, I think, in some references) by multiplication. The vertices and edges of the standard tree are classes of $G^*(v)$ and $G^*(e)$. So, the vertices stabilizers are conjugates of $G$ and the edge stabilizers are conjugates of $H$.
Since $K$ is a subgroup of $G^*$ we have an induced action of $K$ on the standard tree. Let $\Gamma = K \backslash S$ and $D$ be a maximal subtree of $\Gamma$. If $\Sigma$ is a connected transversal of $\Gamma$ in $S$, denote by $\sigma: \Gamma \to \Sigma$ the corresponding bijection. We can construct a graph of groups $(\mathcal{K},\Gamma,D)$ by putting $K(m)= K_{\sigma(m)}$ to be the vertex and edge groups and defining another two maps from $K(m)$ to $K(d_i(m))$ ($i=0,1$).
We have that $K \simeq \pi_1(\mathcal{K},\Gamma,D)$ where the fundamental group has the following presentation:
$$\pi_1(\mathcal{K},\Gamma,D) = \langle t_e, K(v) : R_v, \partial_{0,e}(g)^{t_e} = \partial_{1,e}(g), v \in V(\Gamma), e \in E(\Gamma) - E(D)\rangle$$
where $R_v$ are the relations of $K(v)$. Since $(G^*)_v \simeq G$ and $(G^*)_e \simeq H$, then I think $K_v \simeq \bar{G}$ and $K_e \simeq \bar{G} \cap \partial_0(H)$.
To determine $\Gamma$ we need to determine the orbits of the action of $K$ on $S$. I think the standard tree $S$ is defined by: the edges are $E(S) = G^*/H$ the vertex are $V(S) = G^*/G$, the incidence maps are $d_0(gH) = gH$ and $d_1(gH) = gt^{-1}H$. The quotient $G^* \backslash S$ has only two orbits: one orbit for the vertices, one orbit for the edges. This agree with the fact that $\bar{\Gamma}$ has one vertex and one edge.

How to determine $\Gamma = K \backslash S$?

I think the orbit corresponding to a vertex is a union of orbits of $K$, the same for the orbit corresponding to an edge. But how many? It seems that $\Gamma$ could be infinite. I'm having trouble to understand this graph of groups.

The orbit for a vertex under the action of $G$ on the standard tree $S$ can be divided in $n$ orbits relative to the action of $H$ on $S$, by the equality
$$G^* = \bigcup_1^n g_iK$$
where $|G^*:K| = n$ (can I assume if the index is infinite?). The same for the orbit of an edge. It means that the graph of groups corresponding to $K$ has $n$ vertices and $n$ edges where $n$ is the index of $K$ in $G^*$. The $n$ vertices groups are of the form $K \cap g_iGg_i^{-1}$ where $g_i$ are representative of the cosets. The same for the $n$ edge groups.

If this is correct, how this graph looks like?

Are there $n$ loops? I think $\Gamma$ should be connected.

I must not be understanding your main question. You asked what are the $G$-stabilizers, but you have answered that question already in the previous sentence: they are the conjugates of $G$ and $H$ in the group $G^*$.

@LeeMosher I'm having trouble to understand what they are in the graph of groups. The conjugates of $G$ are isomorphic to $G$, the same for $H$. So, I think the vertex stabilizers of $K$ are isomorphic to $\bar{G}$ and the edge stabilizers are isomorphic to $\bar{G} \cap H$. But how many vertex and edges have the graph of groups of $K$? Is this the "same" graph of groups of $G^*$?

I am confused by your notation. The definition of an HNN extension requires two subgroups $H$ and $K$ of a group $G$ together with an isomorphism $H \to K$. So how do I interpret ${\rm HNN}(G,H,t)$? You appear to have specified only one subgroup of $G$. Are you assuming that $H=K$?

@DerekHolt I edit my question in order to clarify my attempt.

Since you have two monomorphisms from $H$ to $G$, it is not clear what $\bar{G} \cap H$ means. Assuming you mean $\bar{G} \cap \delta_0(H)$, it would not in general be true that $t^{-1}(\bar{G} \cap \delta_0(H))t$ is contained in $\bar{G}$, in which case ${\rm HNN}(\bar{G}, \bar{G} \cap H,t)$ does not make sense.

@DerekHolt oh, I see.
